# prove that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n\le \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n$

Tags: real-analysis

If we have a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $R$,
$b_n = (a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n)/n$

prove that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n\le \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n$

prove that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n\le \liminf_{n\to\infty} b_n$

Could you give me some help?

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part follows from the first by considereing $-a_n$ and $-b_n$.

For the first part: If $u>v>\limsup a_n$ then almost all $a_n$ are $<v$; Why does this imply that almost all $b_n<u$?

Comment: Hi, I completed the first part but I'm not sure how the second part follows from the first by considering -a$_n
$ and -b$_n$. :(